# Line continuation operator not working python

Tags: python-3.6, line-breaks

I am new to Python and I am having issues when breaking a line of code. I am using Python 3.6 on Spyder.

When I try to break any line and I run the code, Python reads only until before the backslash and retrieves and error. For example, I want to break
`a = 1 + 2 + 3` 
into

```
a = (a + b \
     + 3)
```

It gives me the error `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`.

I have checked with and without the backslash, and with different indentations in the second line. 
I have read the way of breaking a line of code is this one...is there anything I have to activate on my IDE or something like that?

Comment: Please give a look at my answer, if it doesn't work, the error should be searched somewhere else. Please post more code if that is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use parenthesis the line break is implicit, so you could break your line after the plus sign like so:

```
a = (a + b +
        3)
```

Or like so:

```
a = (a + b
        + 3)
```

By the guidelines the backslash needs only to be used if necessary, otherwise please use the implicit one.